# Condensing duplicates in a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create change a single row query into a multiple-row query.
I need to grab all id numbers that equal "286" from `table_A` table and grab all student numbers from the table_B table that have a created-at date greater or equal to "2021-08-25 00:00". These values will be inserted into `table_main.X` and `table_main.Y` columns respectively.

Here is the code I was given to work with:

```
INSERT INTO `table_main`(`X`,`Y`) 
SELECT table_A.id, 
       table_B.student 
FROM       `table_A` 
INNER JOIN `table_B` 
WHERE table_A.id = '286' 
  AND table_B.created_at >= '2021-08-25 00:00' 
GROUP BY `student`.
```

I am getting the following error:

```
-- duplicate entry '286-111111' for key table_main.PRIMARY --
```

Is there a way to condense all the duplicates as one when they get entered?

Comment: You need to reveal what the _relationship_ is between the `group_info` and `eal_alert` tables is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am having trouble figuring out how to do that. Could you point me in the right direction?